# Is it safe/correct to grant full access to Everyone on a Windows symlink?

Tags: windows

Does it really matter what the permissions are on a symlink as long as the smymlink target is configured correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say no, with a symbolic link its only linking to a file on the system like a shortcut and all its designed to do is act as a bookmark for easy access from whatever location you put its shortcut at. In this case the only thing that COULD happen to your symbolic link is that if you don't put permissions other people on the system could potentially copy and or delete it but the original documents would be fine.

I did this once on Linux with a Minecraft server at one time and a rogue admin with FTP access thought he was going to "kill" the server by deleting it but unaware to him it was only a symbolic link he had killed and not the entire directory.